# Should we remove the "list" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

The tag [list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) was recently added to a whole bunch of questions. This tag clearly describes the form of what the question is asking for rather than the subject-matter of the question. That's not what tags are supposed to be for, and not what they're generally for.

Here's what our ["Tags" page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) says tags are for:

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Here's what the "[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)" page in our Help Center says:

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>
> Tags can also be used to help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to you.
>
> ...
>
> Do not use [meta-tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`, and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question.
> - **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** For example, the meaning of the tag `[subjective]` is, itself, subjective; the same is true for tags like `[best-practices]` and `[beginner]`. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? Use only tags that have a broadly accepted, objective definition.

The [list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) tag clearly:

- Does not categorize a question with other, [meaningfully] similar questions.
- Does not describe the topic of the question.
- Does not help connect experts with questions they'll be able to answer, as there's no such thing as an expert on Jewish lists.
- Cannot work as the only tag on a question.
- Does not communicate anything about the content of the question.

Can we please remove this tag?

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/the-sources-tag

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/959/759

Comment: I think the tag could be appropriate for a question like "Are you allowed to list the books of Tanakh? I heard it was forbidden". Such a question indeed asks _about_ listing things. I don't know if any of the current questions are of this type, fwiw.

Comment: @DoubleAA formally, perhaps, but is there likely to be anyone out there who's particularly interested in the topic of lists in Judaism?

Comment: Perhaps. A priori we don't know. That's why we just make tags when we get enough q's of a certain type. If somebody is writing their PhD about that, and uses us as a resource by asking lots of questions, then we should have a tag. Again, I don't think we're at that stage yet.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think we're entitled to use our judgement as a community of experts about Judaism, generally.

Comment: I don't see the value of it either; it feels very much like a meta tag.

Comment: Tangent, for future taggers: *please* don't flood the front page with a pervasive change like that.  It pushes other recently-asked (or recently-active) questions out of view before they've had a chance to be seen.   Yes there are other ways to see them, but as a kindness to people looking for answers to new questions, let's try to keep edits like this down to ~10 at a time, ok?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I think that guidance deserves its own post.

Comment: @IsaacMoses yeah, was trying to figure out where to put it (it's not really a *question*, though I guess I could cast it as one), and I haven't searched meta yet to see if it's come up before.  Meanwhile, I figure a comment here is better than nothing.  I'll try to improve on that, b"n.

Comment: @MonicaCellio "Meta is different." :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think your tangent would be better placed as a ping to the recent offender on one of the posts he just blitzkreiged the front pages with.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I've wondered occasionally why the product-recommendation tag isn't a meta tag. Are there experts on Jewish products out there who would be perusing that tag?

Comment: @IsaacMoses How is this different from [tag:sources-mekorot]?

Comment: @yEz [done](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48002/is-there-a-list-of-mitzvos-which-show-respect#comment192336_48002) (CC Isaac).

Comment: @yEz, yeah, that one probably deserves to be dropped as well. But even if that's not practical immediately, nipping [tag:list] and other new meta-tag in the bud is.

Comment: @DoubleAA, see my first and immediately previous comments here

Comment: @IsaacMoses I just added the how-to tag to a question. That also seems rather meta-ish.

Comment: @yEz ברוך שכוונת http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18140932#18140932

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been effected. All instances of [list](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) have been removed (by [Shog9](/users/548/shog9); thanks!).